# Erase word from ruby that contains a certain char

Tags: ruby

As the tittle suggests, I'd like to get some chars and check if the string as any of them. If I suppose, for example, "!" to be forbidden, then `string.replace("",word_with_!)`. How can I check for forbidden chars if forbidden_chars is an array?

```
forbidden_chars = ["!",",",...]

check ARRAY (it is the string split into an array) for forbidden chars
erase all words with forbidden chars
```

Could anyone help me please? I just consider searching for the words with the cards and retrieving index as mandatory in the answer please. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Look at `gsub` method - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-gsub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = 'I like my coffee hot, with no sugar!'

forbidden_chars = ['!', ',']
forbidden_chars_pattern = forbidden_chars.map(&Regexp.method(:escape)).join('|')

string.gsub /\S*(#{forbidden_chars_pattern})\S*/, ''
  # => "I like my coffee  with no "
```

The idea is to match as many non-white space characters as possible `\S*`, followed by any of the forbidden characters `(!|,)`, followed by as many non-white space characters as possible again.

The reason we need the `Regexp.escape` is for the cases when a forbidden character has special regex meaning (like `.`).

Comment: Suppose `string = 'My pet zebra is named "Hank"'` and 
forbidden_chars = ['z']

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'I    like my coffee strong, with no cream or sugar!'
verboten = '!,' 

string.split.select { |s| s.count(verboten).zero? }.join ' '
  #=> "I like my coffee with no cream or"
```

Note this does not preserve the spacing between `"I"` and `"like"` but if there are no extra spaces in `string` it returns a string that has no extra spaces.